# how to add a button within a button on tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, lambda

i have a button in grid, and it already has one command, which just prints text. However i want a button to pop up as well as the text. so long story short, i'm just trying to add a button within a button. (multiple functions within one button basically)
This is what i have so far.

```
def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(text="Hello " + e.get() + "...    text  ", bg='black')
    myLabel.grid(row=60, column=0)

myButton = Button(window, bg='black', text="next", command=myClick)
myButton.grid(row=0, column=13)
```

Comment: What you have does not put a button in a button.  It adds an additional text box to the layout when you click the button.  That's perfectly fine.  Is that working for you?

Comment: yep. thats what i have so far. but im asking how can you put a button in a button :)

Comment: @caterin, what is the purpose of adding a button within a button?

Comment: i want my button to go to a new page where there then can be entry widgets (questionare style)

Comment: You don't really want a button to be drawn on top of another button.  That's a terribly confusing user experience.  If you want your button click to bring up a new page, then why don't you do that?  What's the POINT of what you're asking?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to answer your question once again. Comments in the code will explain some stuff you may ask.

```
def myClick():
    # clearing up the window
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    
    # creating a new page
    myLabel = Label(text="Hello " + e.get() + "...    text  ", bg='black')
    myLabel.grid(row=60, column=0)
    
    newButton = Button(window, bg='black', text="Some button you want to appear")
    newButton.grid(row=60, column=13)

myButton = Button(window, bg='black', text="next", command=myClick)
myButton.grid(row=0, column=13)
```

Comment: thank you it works, but the button wont move no matter how much i change the grid rows and columns :/ @stysan

Comment: that is really bad @caterin

Comment: fixed it nevermind

Comment: alright good! @caterin

Comment: im really sorry, but how would you add a command to that newButton ?         (and once again thank you so much for your help)

Comment: @caterin `newButton = Button(window, bg='black', text="Some button you want to appear", command=yourCommand)`